# How to remove slider nav from 'Slick slider syncing' and show thumbnails instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using [Slick slider syncing](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to show the image by clicking on its thumbnail picture in the slider nav below it. Working code snippet attached.

If you run the snippet, you will see that there are two sliders:

1. 1st one at the top showing the image in big size
2. 2nd one showing a filmstrip like thumbnails, clicking on each image will show the same image on the 1st slider.

[image: Screenshot of the image slider]

***Instead of 2nd slider, I want to show images in thumbnails like the one attached in the picture below and still want it to work in the same way i.e. whenever I click on any of the image in thumbnails, it should show the same image in 1st slider.***

[image: Screenshot of what I want to show the slider like]

Can someone help me please? Don't know how to make it work.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-for').slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     arrows: false,
     fade: true,
     asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
   });
   $('.slider-nav').slick({
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     asNavFor: '.slider-for',
     dots: true,
     centerMode: true,
     focusOnSelect: true
   });
 });
```

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}



@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -10px\9; /*lte IE 8*/
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0px;
    padding: 0;
 
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .8;
    color: #ffb608;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: 1;
 font-size:12px;
    color: #ffb608;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style>
.pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: grey;
}

.pink {background-color: pink;}
.orange {background-color: orange;}
.green {background-color: lightgreen;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="slider-for">
    <div class="pink pic">1</div>
    <div class="orange pic">2</div>
    <div class="green pic">3</div>
    <div class="orange pic">4</div>
    <div class="pink pic">5</div>
    <div class="green pic">6</div>
    <div class="pink pic">7</div>
    <div class="green pic">8</div>
    <div class="orange pic">9</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div class="pink pic">1</div>
    <div class="orange pic">2</div>
    <div class="green pic">3</div>
    <div class="orange pic">4</div>
    <div class="pink pic">5</div>
    <div class="green pic">6</div>
    <div class="pink pic">7</div>
    <div class="green pic">8</div>
    <div class="orange pic">9</div>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use slickGoTo() to navigate to slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pen that demonstrate that, now change css according to your need

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLExGd

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slideshow").slick({
        dots: true
    });
    $(".menu a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        slideIndex = $(this).index();
        $( '.slideshow' ).slickGoTo( parseInt(slideIndex) );
    });
});
```

```css
a img {width:100px}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css"/>
    <style>
        .menu {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container {
            width: 400px;
            margin:1em auto;
        }
        .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before  {
            color: gray ! important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-01/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-02/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-03/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-04/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-05/"></a> 

</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-01/"></div>
        <div><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-02/"></div>
        <div><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-03/"></div>
        <div><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-04/"></div>
        <div><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/IMAGE-05/"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"/></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```